# Change tier in bulk for Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have some thousands of blobs with a given suffix I want to assign to a new tier (hot to archive) in bulk. I know it is possible to manually change the tier on portal or through a REST request pointing to a specific blob. Is there a way to set tiers in bulk with a wildcard or something similar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's really as simple as 3 lines.

```
#Get stroage account 
$straccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -Name xxxxxx -ResourceGroupName xxxxxxxxxxxxx

#Get all the blobs in container
$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container test -Context $straccount.Context

#Set tier of all the blobs to Archive
$blobs.icloudblob.setstandardblobtier("Archive")
```

Just make sure the container only have block blob or you will get error. Last i checked Archive tier is only support by block blob.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob?view=azure-dotnet

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey the account in question does have append blobs and I do not want to set all to Archive, only certain ones with a specific suffix

Comment: You can do prefix. 

$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container test -Context $straccount.Context -Prefix xxxxxxx

Comment: These should also work, tough not test or recommended.  $blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container test -Context $straccount.Context -Blob "*test"

Comment: I don't think that code will work, since you're retrieving into `$blobs` and then working with `$blob`. Also, you'd have to loop through all blob names inside of  `$blobs` - each tier change is an individual call; there's no way to set all blobs within a container, with a single action.

Comment: Also, I don't really agree with referring to this (or any programming solution someone doesn't know about) as "really as simple as..." Requires knowing about the `icloudblob` object which has over 100 methods. And requires knowledge that this is a significant number of network transactions (and will likely be long-running if you have thousands or millions of blobs).